# Change position UIAlertController (UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet)

Tags: objective-c, uialertcontroller

i need to change the default postition where it shows the UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet.

Default position is

[image]

I need to be

[image]

is that possible?

Comment: both screen showing same order Cancel, Facebook, Twiter . can you please update your desired order.

Comment: it seems I explained myself wrong and i apologize. What i want is that "gap" i show in the second image (i edited it)

Answer (score -1):

UIAlertController action row position will always depends on order of adding UIAlertAction.

Try below code :

UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                           alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                           message:nil
                           preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

```
    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel action")
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                   {
                                       NSLog(@"Cancel action");
                                   }];
    UIAlertAction *FacebookAction = [UIAlertAction
                                    actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Facebook", @"Facebook")
                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                    {

                                        NSLog(@"Show facebook action action");
                                    }];

    UIAlertAction *twitterAction = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Twitter", @"Twitter")
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"Show Twiter action");
                               }];

    [alertController addAction:cancelAction]; // 1th row from bottom
    [alertController addAction:twitterAction]; // 2nd row from bottom
    [alertController addAction:FacebookAction]; // 3rd row from bottom
```

Comment: it seems I explained myself wrong and i apologize. What i want is that "gap" i show in the second image (i edited it)